# Magento Admin Login Gives Exception

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework

I am using Magento 1.2.2 version. When I try to login from admin panel, it throws me exceptions as followings:

`Zend_Acl_Exception: Resource 'admin/system/config/fraud_detection' not found in C:\Apps\xampp\1.8.0\htdocs\myproject\lib\Zend\Acl.php on line 365`

`Zend_Acl_Exception: Resource 'admin/system/enterprise_staging/staging_grid/action' not found in C:\Apps\xampp\1.8.0\htdocs\myproject\lib\Zend\Acl.php on line 365`

I can't access my admin panel.

Can you give me a suggestion why am I getting such exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

See in your magento root folder - if there is any maintenance flag file is created. If there then delete & try to login again by restart your lampp

Comment: No, there is no such file in my Magento root folder.

Answer (score 0):

apparently you changed enough of your application that now your acl(access control list) plugin is having a nervous breakdown.

Now I can't tell what's in your acl plugin (located at /zend_medaffiliate/library/Svit/Controller/Plugin/Acl.php) that's causing the problem but to turn it off until you can get around to fixing it should be simple.

The plugin will be registered in either your application.ini or your Bootstrap.php and you are looking for a line that addresses "Svit_Controller_Plugin_Acl".

In your application.ini the line might look similar to: resources.frontController.plugins.acl = "Svit_Controller_Plugin_Acl"